# what is tomcat's user directory and how to find it in ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat

I have installed apache-tomcat 8.0.30 in etc folder. How can I find the **tomcat's user directory** in ubuntu?

Which one is tomcat's user directory? what is meant by user directory? is it the configuration directory? temp directory?there are so many directories.

I am following an instruction on a tutorial and it say's tomcat's user directory but I am not sure which directory it means.

Also when I install tomcat in **etc** folder, does it create a directory in /usr/share/tomcat{X} ? because there was none but I created it and I don't think the tutorial means this folder because it was not created during installation.

thanks!

Comment: then which one is tomcat's user directory? what is meant by user directory? is it the configuration directory? temp directory?there are so many directories.

Comment: Since no one else appears to be able to give you a correct answer, the home directory is specified in the /etc/passwd file. Find the entry for the tomcat user and the home directory will be listed as the second to last value. In my install, that is /var/lib/tomcat8 but yours may be different.  For everyone else, the tomcat user that OP is referring to is the user account under which the tomcat service is run.

Comment: You can also simply type `echo ~<username>` to display the user's home directory. In the case of the tomcat8 user, this would be `echo ~tomcat8`

Answer (score 0):

There are three **important** directories for Tomcat:

```
 /etc/tomcat{X} for configuration 

 /etc/tomcat{X} for runtime, called CATALINA_HOME

 /usr/share/tomcat{X}-root for webapps
```

The alternative path to Tomcat, called `CATALINA_BASE`, is

```
   /var/lib/tomcat{X}
```

The `temp` folder for `Tomcat` is

```
  /tmp/tomcat{X}-tomcat{X}-tmp
```

All the above paths work for Tomcat 6, 7, and 8.

Replace `{X}` with the appropriate Tomcat major version number, e.g.

```
 /etc/tomcat8.
```

It should work

Comment: so which is the user directory?

Comment: it depends what you're looking for. If your apps, it should be in `share`

Comment: hi, thanks for replies, during installation no folder was created in /usr/share?

Comment: you're using the latest version of tomcat, so check Catalina_home I mean 'etc/tomcat', there might be already your webapps

Comment: i found the webapps folder but this is not the problem. i am following a tutorial that says- mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/.sfile
ln -s /etc/myfolder/file.name /usr/share/tomcat7/.sfile   -now as i installed apache-tomcat-8.0.30 in /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30 I don't have tomcat7 folder in the /usr/share, so how to proceed with the symlink steps as instructed by the tutorial?

Comment: find tutorial with tomcat8. I don't think you neex to add this link